# ErrorCode [FNF], Message [FNF: Required Local file /var/tmp/oozie/oozie-oozi7179698092277115649.dir/ssh/ssh-base.sh not present.]

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am facing below error while running oozie job in SSH Action

Please help me how to resolve it,

```
JOB[0000117-160531014243114-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000117-160531014243114-oozie-oozi-W@load_hadoop] Attempting to copy ssh base scripts to remote host [jithin@edgenode]
2016-07-20 05:10:10,834  WARN SshActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[masternode.cityanalytics.ibm.com] USER[jithin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Dallas_Test] JOB[0000117-160531014243114-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000117-160531014243114-oozie-oozi-W@load_hadoop] Error while executing ssh EXECUTION
2016-07-20 05:10:10,834  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[masternode.cityanalytics.ibm.com] USER[jithin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Dallas_Test] JOB[0000117-160531014243114-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000117-160531014243114-oozie-oozi-W@load_hadoop] Error starting action [load_hadoop]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [FNF], Message [FNF: Required Local file /var/tmp/oozie/oozie-oozi7179698092277115649.dir/ssh/ssh-base.sh not present.]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: FNF: Required Local file /var/tmp/oozie/oozie-oozi7179698092277115649.dir/ssh/ssh-base.sh not present.
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.execute(SshActionExecutor.java:572)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.start(SshActionExecutor.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Required Local file /var/tmp/oozie/oozie-oozi7179698092277115649.dir/ssh/ssh-base.sh not present.
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.setupRemote(SshActionExecutor.java:367)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor$1.call(SshActionExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor$1.call(SshActionExecutor.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ssh.SshActionExecutor.execute(SshActionExecutor.java:550)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: attaching workflow.xml and coordinator properties file.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is solved by restarting oozie server. Some one might have removed that required folder and files from oozie server. Once you restarted oozie server, oozie will create this folder directory structure and will copy ssh-wrapper.sh and ssh-base.sh files. Then it started processing jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue while running my Oozie workflow with an ssh action.

**Issue:**

```
FNF: Required Local file /var/tmp/oozie/oozie-oozi3389039347561142826.dir/ssh/ssh-base.sh not present.
```

**Solution:**

I restarted the oozie server and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue, override TMP directory used by setting the following configuration.This can point to any directory that oozie is able to **write to**. Do the following;

1. go to **Cloudera Manager > Oozie > Java Configuration Options for Oozie Server**
2. **-Djava.io.tmpdir=/new/directory**